# sbt-assembly shading error with shapeless in ubuntu

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shapeless, sbt-assembly, pureconfig

I’m having a weird issue with `sbt-assembly` if anyone could help

When trying to create fat jar to deploy to Spark with shading applied to `shapeless` libraries, I am seeing some classes not being renamed when ran in an Ubuntu machine while everything gets renamed fine when the `sbt assembly` is ran in Mac.

Here’s the shading config

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "shadedshapeless.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2")
    .inLibrary("com.github.pureconfig" % "pureconfig_2.11" % "0.7.0")
    .inProject)
```

When ran in Mac, these classes are renamed for pattern `shapeless/Generic*`

```
Renamed shapeless/Generic$.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic$.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1$.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1$.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1$class.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1$class.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic10$class.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic10$class.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic10.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic10.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1Macros$$anonfun$1.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1Macros$$anonfun$1.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1Macros$$anonfun$2.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1Macros$$anonfun$2.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1Macros.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1Macros.class
Renamed shapeless/GenericMacros$$anonfun$23.class -> shadedshapeless/GenericMacros$$anonfun$23.class
Renamed shapeless/GenericMacros.class -> shadedshapeless/GenericMacros.class
```

but when ran in Ubuntu, for the pattern `shapless/Generic*` only these things are renamed

```
Renamed shapeless/GenericMacros$$anonfun$23.class -> shadedshapeless/GenericMacros$$anonfun$23.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1Macros$$anonfun$1.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1Macros$$anonfun$1.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1$.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1$.class
Renamed shapeless/Generic1.class -> shadedshapeless/Generic1.class
```

I chose the pattern `shapeless/Generic*` coz when am providing the fat jar (produced in Ubuntu) to `spark-submit` then am getting the error right away (probably coming from `pureconfig`)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shadedshapeless/Generic
```

*No error occurs when fat jar produced in Mac is being fed to `spark-submit`*

Comment: I have the same issue on windows sub-system vs linux. Some classes inside shapeless is not renamed. Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why on Ubuntu shading works differently from MacOs but one issue that I see is that you are shading only part of shapeless. I don't think this is a good idea and can give you problems because you'll mix different versions of shapeless. My suggestion is to try shading shapeless entirely for PureConfig. Just add

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "new_shapeless.@1").inAll)
```

to your sbt file. This solution has been tested by me on Ubuntu 16.04 with PureConfig 7.2 and Spark 2.1.0. See the [FAQ section of PureConfig about this issue](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig#how-can-i-use-pureconfig-with-spark-210-problematic-shapeless-dependency).